# Usage of different prepositions after 'common'

Tags: prepositions

How does the meaning change with the usage of different prepositions after 'common' :

- something common for people,
- something common to people,
- something common in people

Comment: I believe you can use any of them, depending on context. For example, *Allergies are not (something) common **in** breast-fed babies.* *Computers and mobile phones are (something) common **to** us nowadays.* However, I think *for* might be more appropriate in another constructions, e.g. *It's common **for** people to bring their own rackets.*

Comment: It's usually best if you include complete sentences as examples.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to argue that, of all the three cases proposed by the OP:

1. something common to people
2. something common for people
3. something common in people

only in the first case, the preposition is linking to the adjective `common`. In the other two cases, the phrases `for people` and `in people` are actually independent adverbial phrases.

Following are the arguments supporting this statement:

## The English Collocation Dictionary (ozdic.com)

[Ozdic.com](http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/common) lists `to` as the only preposition used to complement the adjective `common`. Ozdic gives the following example of use:

> This attitude is common to most young men in the armed services

Immediately, the question raises: how can we interpret the other two cases in the OP's question? Here's how:

## The construct `for + (object) + to + (infinitive-verb)`

I argue that OP's case using preposition `for` is actually a case of the construct `for + (object) + to + (infinitive-verb)`. Let's look at a full example:

> It is common for the youngers to lack discretion

This example could be paraphrased as: `it is common that the youngers lack discretion`; showing that in this type of construct, `for the youngers` does not really complement `common` but `to lack discretion`.

Note that in this construct the focus is on the infinitive verb `to lack discretion` rather than the object `the youngers`.

## The adverbial phrase `in  + (location)`

Again, I argue that in this case the preposition `in` does not link to adjective `common`, but rather it forms the adverbial phrase `in + (location)`. Let's look at a full example:

> Allergies are not common in breast-fed babies

To illustrate that the adverbial phrase `in breast-fed babies` does not link to adjective `common`, let's rephrase the adverbial phrase:

> Allergies are not common before babies are weaned

Answer (score 0):

It all depends which case you are talking about...

Maybe, this makes it clearer.

> It's **common for** people to react badly if the government does not protect their rights. 
>   The issue of racism is **common to** people of X. 
>   These symptoms are quite **common in** people above age 65.

Comment: If something is common to two or more people or groups, it is done, possessed, or used by them all.   ⇒ Moldavians and Romanians share a common language.   ⇒ [+ to] Such behaviour is common to all young people. _from Collins Dictionary_ [link](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-cobuild-learners/common)